# Convergence in $L^2(\Bbb R)$ implies convergence of the norms

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

If $||f_n-f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}\to 0$ is it always true that $||f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}=\lim_{n\to\infty}||f_n||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$?

Comment: This holds in any normed linear space, Some textbooks merely mention it, or put it in the exercises.

Comment: Give this a try using a triangle inequality argument.

Answer (score 5):

Triangle inequality

$$|\, ||f_n ||_2 -|| f ||_2\, |\leq ||f_n-f||_2$$